# Passing data when finishing activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

in order to learn Android I'm trying to mimic the example given on the [developers page regarding `Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout), only that instead of different loaded texts I have different Fragments that do different tasks. Sadly I have problems with several issues (like duplicate Fragments in LogCat), but here I would like to address the following:

In the example, `finish()` is used in `onCreate` to exit the current "DetailActivity" in portrait mode and to return back to the list of titles. I thought that was rather elegant, but what if I have data in the attached `Fragment` that I want to save?

Going from landscape to portrait would be no problem, I guess, I could just start the intent with the extra info (maybe in form of a `Bundle`?) and pass that data on when creating the `Fragment` that is attached to the new `Activity`.

However, going from portrait to landscape...how do I pass data that I might have generated in the attached `Fragment` to the parent `Activity` and then back to the other one (with the two `Fragments`) an orientation change? All of this would have to be done before calling `finish()` in `onCreate()`, right!?!

Thank you in advance for your help!